# Remove padding/margin above Fragment in Leanback

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, leanback

I'm creating an app with Leanback's PlaybackSupportFragment. I want the LinearLayout and contents below it to be moved up so that the LinearLayout aligns with the top of the VeticalGridView.

[image]

There is no reference to container_list anywhere in Android Studio. Is there a way to move a LinearLayout if I don't have access to the container it is in?